# Jquery find element with variable in an xml document?

Tags: jquery

Basically language return a jquery object -> which is either 'fr' or 'en', with this information I can search in a xml file which on some element have either 'fr' or 'en'

```
    var language = $('#language').attr('language'),

    title = $(queryXml).find("title[lang=" + language+ "]").text();
```

console.log(language); -> return fr

If I use var language = 'en', or 'fr' it works perfectly, but since I want jQuery to dynamically find the current language I used $('#language').attr('language').

So normally if I want to display language content, I think I should use language.[0] but it doesn't work inside a jquery function... (I just started using jquery like recently, so correct me please. I learned a lot by test)

Comment: Do you actually have an element with an id 'language' in your DOM with the value *en* or *fr*?

Comment: yes, well I just tested again by using that     title = $(queryXml).find("title[lang=" + $('#language').attr('language') + "]").text();
and it works perfectly, but I have to copy paste it like 4 times, it's so much better to asign it into a variable. Actually the question should be like that how can I convert var language = $('#language').attr('language'). into a string so when I do the find function it will take into account that language is = either to en or fr. If there is other suggestion please provide thanx

Answer (score 0):

since using var language =  $('#language').attr('language') will return an object, I can't use it on .find() but whenever I change my code from title = $(queryXml).find("title[lang=" + language+ "]").text(); to  title = $(queryXml).find("title[lang=" + $('#language').attr('language') + "]").text(); it works.

So what I can do is creating an object with a key function jQuery.fn.extend({
    language: $('#language').attr('language'),

});

each time I perform thePlate = queryXml.find('plate').eq(l).find('description[lang='+jQuery.fn.language+']').text(); it will works perfectly, is like asigning a function to a variable. whenever I call jQuery.fn.language it call $('#language').attr('language')

Hope it can help someone